# Android - how can I check if text fits completely inside a view?

Tags: android, button, resize, textview

I have a series of buttons and textviews that I would like to always be square and always fit the amount of text inside them. If the view has one word in it, it will be a small square. If the view has a whole sentence, it will be a square large enough to fit the entire sentence.

How can I check if text fits inside a view both horizontally AND vertically? I've only seen the ability to check if the first line of text fits in a view horizontally. But what if the first line of text fits and the second or third line gets cut off? How can I tell if that is happening in code so that I can increase the size of the view?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a way to do fit always the text inside a background, you have to use a nine-patch image or 9.png http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html
I think it will be easier to use a 9 patch than checking text size.

Comment: @jsaye you should post this as an answer. That's the right answer imho.

Comment: This is the easy way to go (without coding), basically a picture with a border of 1 transparent pixel. Then you go to your android-sdk/tools folder, and you will have to look for the draw9patch.exe. With this program allows you to specify which pixels of  your background will expand/contract defining them with black pixels.

Comment: There is the possibility to create your own TexTview class, something like public class myTextView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable, since you will have to define how your view is displayed then you can create a Paint object, put a text in that object and before painting it see if it fits inside your canvas, that should be something more adjusted to what you asked.

Comment: I have a custom view that extends TextView. When I override the onDraw method I have access to the canvas. How do I go about checking if the text fits in the paint and that the paint fits in the canvas? I only see methods that seem to measure the width of text.

As for the nine-patch, the views have a gradient background color and I think using a nine-patch will cause the gradient to look different when the view expands.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the text you can add your text with android:text="text" and review if it fits correctly on your graphical view of the XML file, playing with the screen sizes. Also you can use a relative size for the text like pixels (px) to be more flexible with different screens